# Doxygen does not process my source file comments

Tags: doxygen

I'm new with Doxygen, and i have been commenting my functions with the Qt style approach:

```
/*! .. */
```

Doxygen however only picks up my header files and does not generate documentation of any text that is within these comments.

The html file rendered, shows a completely empty main page, "Classes' only list the structs
that are found in the header files and "Files" lists only the same header files in the project.

What may cause this behavior, or is this to be expected? 
Am i missing something? The only thing i changed in the configuration file was the INPUT directory to be "src".

No errors during compilation, i see that it is preprocessing and parsing my .c files. And at some point it says this, but only for the header files

```
Generating code for file src/foo.h...
Generating code for file src/bar.h...
etc.
```

Finally i get some warnings about structs not being documented, but nothing about the functions I want to have actually documented.

Comment: Does this related question help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11029676/623518

Comment: Yes, thanks. When changing "EXTRACT_ALL = NO" to "YES", doxygen finds all my .c and .h files and also renders them regardless of the functions having comments or not. But now i am not sure if doxygen thinks of my project ass a c++ project, It is actually a c project. But whenever i look at "Member Data Documentation" for example is i see things like foo::bar, i wonder why..

Comment: OK, try setting `EXTRACT_ALL` back to `NO`, and add a [`\file`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdfile) directive to the files that you want documented, then only documented functions will be present in the generated documentation. Also, if you have a C project, set `OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C` in your configuration file; Doxygen is, by default, optimised for C++. I would review the Doxygen documentation to get familiar with other [configuration options](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html) that might be appropriate for your project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in doxygen creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029347/error-in-doxygen-creation)